# Mongoose Validation Logic Failing on Number Comparisons

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

So I'm working a reservation system, or trying to. I have a start_block and end_block, ints representing reservable times in the day.

My Schema is as follows:

```
var ReservationSchema = new Schema({
  rid: {type: Number},
  day: {type: Date},
  start_block: {type: Number},
  end_block: {type: Number},
  kind: {type: String},
  agent: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  primary_client: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  secondary_clients: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  created_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updated_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

My Validation is as follows:

```
ReservationSchema.pre("validate", function (next, done) {
  var self = this;
  console.log("being validated");
  mongoose.models["Reservation"]
    .findOne({
      $or: [
        {start_block: {$gte: self.start_block, $lte: self.end_block}, rid: self.rid},
        {end_block: {$gte: self.start_block, $lte: self.end_block}, rid: self.rid}
      ]
    }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        done(err);
      } else if (user) {
        console.log("blocked!!!!");
        self.invalidate("start_block", "Times overlap");
        done(new Error("Times Slots Cannot Overlap"));
      } else {
        console.log("passed");
        done();
      }
    });
  next();
});
```

My seeding of types is here:

```
Reservation.find({}).remove(function(){
  User.find({}).limit(1)
    .exec(function (err, result) {
      if(err) throw err;
      var person = result[0];
      if(person != null){
        for(var i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
          var start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 1;
          Reservation.create({
            rid: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
            day: new Date("1985-10-06"),
            start_block: start,

            end_block: start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 2,
            agent: person._id,
            primary_client: person._id,
            kind: "Reservation"
          });
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```

A portion of my output logs when seeding, various crazy console logs...
being validated

```
{ [CastError: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "end_block"]
  message: 'Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "end_block"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'number',
  value: undefined,
  path: 'end_block' }
being validated
being validated
{ [CastError: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "end_block"]
  message: 'Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "end_block"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'number',
  value: undefined,
  path: 'end_block' }
passed
passed
```

Finally, the result is that the bookings still overlap when place on a div based table... Been trying to get this for quite a few hours and failed google searches have brought me here in hopes of brighter minds. Thank you!

Edit: Cleared up extra blank creation which cleaned up logs. But still can not figure out why every condition passes without finding a overlapping slot. There must be a logic issue. I've written it out and don't see it...

Here is what he overlap looks like...
[image: Over lapping reservations]

Reservation 19 is overlapping two other reservations

I've rewritten my rules 100 times, here are what they look like now..

```
.findOne({
  $or: [
    {start_block: {$gte: self.start_block, $lt: self.end_block}, rid: self.rid},
    {start_block: {$gt: self.start_block, $lte: self.end_block}, rid: self.rid},
    {end_block: {$lte: self.start_block, $gt: self.end_block}, rid: self.rid},
    {end_block: {$lt: self.start_block, $gte: self.end_block}, rid: self.rid}
  ]
}, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error)');
    console.log(err);
    done(err);
  } else if (user) {
    console.log("blocked!!!!");
    self.invalidate("start_block", "Times overlap");
    done(new Error("Times Slots Cannot Overlap"));
  } else {
    console.log("passed");
    done();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's there, but you're passing an empty `{}` object as a second parameter to your `Reservation.create` call.  That will be treated as a second doc to create, but it doesn't have the fields your validator is expecting.

So remove that second parameter so that the call looks like this instead:

```
Reservation.create({
  rid: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
  day: new Date("1985-10-06"),
  start_block: start,

  end_block: start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 2,
  agent: person._id,
  primary_client: person._id,
  kind: "Reservation"
});
```